# Is there a way to more efficiently read binary doubles from file into an array of floats?

Tags: c++, performance, binary, ifstream

Is there a better way to read binary doubles from file and ultimately put the values into a vector of floats, than an obvious solution such as this?

```
    vector< double > dv( N );

    ifstream inFile( path ); 
    inFile.read( ( char* ) dv.data(), N*sizeof( double ) );
    inFile.close();

    vector< float > fv( dv.begin(), dv.end() );
```

Comment: What about this solution makes you unhappy?

Comment: There are certainly other ways of doing it, if they are more efficient only benchmarking will tell.

Comment: The only optimization I can see would be to mmap the file (or use file mapping on windows) and avoid the alloc and copy into the double vector.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a separate `std::vector<double>` at all.

You can use a manual reading loop:

```
std::vector<float> fv; 
fv.reserve(N);

std::ifstream inFile(path); 

double d;
while (inFile.read((char*)&d, sizeof(d)))
    fv.push_back(static_cast<float>(d));

inFile.close();
```

Alternatively, you can use [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) to populate the `std::vector<float>` directly from the `std::ifstream`:

```
class readDoubleToFloat {
    double data;
public:
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &is, readDoubleToFloat &val) {
        is.read((char*)&(val.data), sizeof(double));
        return is;
    }
    operator float() const { return static_cast<float>(data); }    
};

std::ifstream inFile(path); 

std::vector<float> fv; 
fv.reserve(N);

std::copy(
    std::istream_iterator<readDoubleToFloat>(inFile),
    std::istream_iterator<readDoubleToFloat>(),
    std::back_inserter(fv));

inFile.close();
```

Comment: The question was about efficiency - if the concern is run time (and N is non-trivial), the version in the question is more efficient than either of yours. It does a single read and 2 allocs (mostly because the original question knows N up front). Your versions do N reads and probably log N allocs. If the concern is space, it's probably close - 2 vectors in the question vs the re-allocs in your version.

Comment: If you know N up front, you can `reserve()` the size of the vector before loading it, then the reads will not do any reallocs.

Comment: "If you know N up front, you can reserve() the size of the vector before loading it" - that was my point. but the allocs are still only linear amortized time. I think the bigger performance issue would be the reads of one double at a time in a loop